# std::copy from memory allocated with HeapAlloc()

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm implementing a custom class for hash computation using the [MS CNG API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-portal) using sample code from [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/creating-a-hash-with-cng)

The function below is a shortened version including only the portion that is relevant for discussion (see comments):

```
// [in] data, [in] size, [out] hash
bool Hash::compute(const BYTE* data, DWORD size, std::vector<BYTE>& hash)
{
    // ...

    // A buffer that receives the size of a hash
    DWORD hash_size; // = initialized elsewhere;

    BYTE* pHash = static_cast<PBYTE>(HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, hash_size));

    if (pHash != nullptr)
    {
        // Initialization where hash_handle is BCRYPT_HASH_HANDLE
        BCryptFinishHash(hash_handle, pHash, hash_size, 0));

        hash.clear();
        hash.reserve(hash_size);

        #if TRUE
        // This asserts with:
        // Expression: Cannot seek vector iterator after end
        std::copy(pHash, pHash + hash_size, hash.begin());

        #else

        // This works fine
        for (int i = 0; i < hash_size; ++i)
            hash.push_back(pHash[i]);

        // This also works
        // hash.assign(pHash, pHash + hash_size);
        #endif

        hash.shrink_to_fit();
        return HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pHash) != FALSE;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I have two problems,
first the `pHash` pointer is allocated with `HeapAlloc()` which allocates non-movable memory and since this class is part of a DLL I can't let the caller pass a destination pointer to be used directly through function parameter because `HeapAlloc()` will fail to allocate it, for this reason I'm copying the hash value to the caller's vector.

So the first question is, can I avoid copying hash value and if so how?

Secondly the issue as you can see is that `std::copy` fails with an iterator error put into comment, I would like to know why it fails, and why copying with for loop works in contrast.

Comment: you need to use [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) if you want `std::copy` to `push_back` elements for you

Comment: At that point `hash` is still a vector with 0 elements so you cannot access any of the elements because there are none

Comment: I do not understand the purpose of HeapAlloc and HeapFree here? You allocate some uninitialized memory and then copy it into a vector?

Comment: @user253751 the API requires non-movable memory which is what HeapAlloc does, `pHash` is initialzed elsewhere I omitted that part.

Comment: What is non-movable memory and why is it required?

Comment: @user253751 I think it's non-paged area, but I'm new to this kind of allocation, sadly normal way of allocation doesn't work.

Comment: HeapAlloc does not allocate non-paged area

Comment: `HeapAlloc` does nothing useful these days (outside of a few archaic WIN32 APIs), just allocate memory for the output of `BCryptFinishHash` normally, perhaps as a `std::vector<UCHAR>`.

Comment: @PaulSanders I did pass buffer of the vector ex. `hash.data()` the function succeeds but vector remains empty (I did resize it prior to that)

Comment: @PaulSanders `any pointers passed to the BCryptFinishHash function must refer to nonpaged (or locked) memory` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptfinishhash

Comment: @metablaster how did you resize it? is it the same way you "resize" it in this HeapAlloc code, which is to say, you don't resize it at all?

Comment: @metablaster _any pointers passed to the BCryptFinishHash function must refer to nonpaged (or locked) memory_ That applies only to kernel mode code.  From user mode it just wants a valid pointer to a sufficiently large buffer, anything will do.  Not sure why the function isn't doing what you want, what do you mean by 'empty'?

Comment: @user253751 vector::resize does the trick, thanks for spotting this

Comment: @PaulSanders thank, I see now, I misread that it applies to kernel mode only, my issue is now solved, thank you guys!

Comment: Glad it's working now.  You can answer your own question, if you feel you have something worth sharing.

Comment: It's still unknown why `std::copy` fails which is the tile of the question, so I'll leave it as it is. but otherwise there is no need to copy now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments to my question we determined that copy is not needed, and the solution is to resize vector and get buffer to the vector directly.

What remains unknown is why `std::copy` fails, so this is just a partial answer to the problem.

Fixed sample:

```
// [in] data, [in] size, [out] hash
bool Hash::compute(const BYTE* data, DWORD size, std::vector<BYTE>& hash)
{
    // ...

    // A buffer that receives the size of a hash
    DWORD hash_size; // = initialized elsewhere;

    hash.clear();
    hash.resize(hash_size);

    // Initialization where hash_handle is BCRYPT_HASH_HANDLE
    NTSTATUS status = BCryptFinishHash(hash_handle, hash.data(), hash_size, 0));

    hash.shrink_to_fit();
    return NT_SUCCESS(status);
}
```

Comment: I think the first comment already answers why `std::copy` fails.

Comment: Thank you, it seems I ignored the comment from @Allan birtless, I didn't know `std::copy` can take `back_inserter` as 3rd argument.